# Do CodeIgniter modules work for Kohana?

Tags: codeigniter, kohana

CodeIgniter's got a slew of modules (http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Special:Titles/), but all I can find for Kohana (CI's fork) is http://dev.kohanaframework.org/projects/.  Is the assumption that CI modules work in Kohana (or at least can be massaged to without too much effort), or is it just that Kohana's got fewer modules?

Answer (score 3):

Kohana is no longer simply a "CodeIgniter fork" and has not been for a while so sadly the code cannot be simply copied and pasted across.

Also, CodeIgniter does not have modules, just MVC components, libraries and helpers so I'm not sure what you would be copying from CodeIgniter. :-)

Comment: It is possible to copy and paste code across, though minor modifications will need to be made (i.e. to cater for the K3 filesystem and removing usage of ci_instance() etc.)

Comment: What code would you be copying and pasting across? Helpers wont work properly, anything calling the super-global wont work, anything using any of the core functions wont work... Yes you can copy over REALLY generic library files like SimplePie but that is not a "CI Module". We need to make it clear to people that the code is not the same, wether its minor tweaks or a massive overhaul, most stuff wont work.

Answer (score 2):

Many of Kohana's modules are on GitHub in the [following 424 repositories](http://github.com/search?langOverride=&q=kohana&repo=&start_value=1&type=Repositories).

This repository (kohana-universe) tracks over 111 modules for you.

Comment: This is probably the best way to go about finding modules

Comment: I was going to recommend [kohana-universe](http://github.com/kolanos/kohana-universe) as well.

Answer (score 0):

The best part about Kohana is that most 3rd party classes and modules can be used within Kohana either with no effort at all or with a simple reorganization of the class structure.

The latest version, 3.0, is very flexible and has very few restrictions on what if allows you to do.

Here's a good place to start: http://kohanaframework.org/guide/using.autoloading